# upload zip file

Tags: php

how to upload a .zip file through php code?

Comment: how you are uploading other files nothing to do special with zip files

Comment: Is PHP the client (e.g. curl) or the server for the ZIP transfer?

Answer (score 2):

This code works for me!

```
<?php

if (($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/gif") || ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "application/zip") && ($_FILES["file"]["size"] < 20000))
    {
    if ($_FILES["file"]["error"] > 0)
        {
        echo "Return Code: " . $_FILES["file"]["error"] . "<br />";
        }
      else
        {
        echo "<img src=\"images/logo-top.jpg\"/>";
        echo "Thank you<br />";
        if (file_exists("upload/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]))
            {
            echo $_FILES["file"]["name"] . " already exists. ";
            }
          else
            {
            move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], "upload/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
            }
        }
    }
  else
    {
    echo "<img src=\"images/logo-top.jpg\"/><br />";
    echo "Invalid file";
    }

?>
```

Answer (score 1):

[Check out the upload file tutorial](http://www.tizag.com/phpT/fileupload.php)

Make sure to specify proper settings for:

- file_uploads
- upload_max_filesize
- memory_limit
- max_execution_time
- post_max_size

See:

- [How to optimize your PHP installation to handle large file uploads](http://www.tizag.com/phpT/fileupload.php)